# Recycle view doesn't display text fully set top constraint to a text view

Tags: android

I am trying on a layout as below:

- A text view.
- A recycle view (consist of 2 text view: title and description)under that text view.

**Result**: Recycle view doesn't display texts fully when I scroll text.
It is the same that losing some end lines of texts corresponding height of that Text View.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Text Title"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="description text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text" 
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

and recycle layout is:
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_CHECK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
 />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_CHECK" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please post the image and your code

Comment: Make sure you have set height of the adapter's rowview as wrap_content. So as height of textview.

Comment: why dont you just use a ScrollView if you only need to display 2 items? RecyclerViews are usually used to handle big lists

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Both the Textview and RecyclerView inside the RelativeLayout and give **android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_id"** as follow

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/lot_number_layout">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_po_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"
             android:visibility="visible"
             android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_po_number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

otherwise, use LinerLayout and give the **orientation: vertical** and insert the TextView and RecyclerView inside the LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines of code to your `TextView`s

```
android:ellipsize = "end"
android:maxLines = "1"
```

The whole code would be

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:ellipsize = "end"
    android:maxLines = "1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Text Title"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:ellipsize = "end"
    android:maxLines = "1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="description text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text" 
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. It makes 3 dots on text. :)

Comment: Yes it will since i am giving ellepsize. Didn't it what you want? Should I update it?